# Character creation tutorial recommendations

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I want to learn how to create characters, I would say that I am at an **intermediate** level in blender , my end goal is to be able to create really realistic characters but I know that I need to learn a lot before I am able to do that.

What **character tutorials** do you guys recommend? I would prefer if it was aimed at people that already have a decent understanding of blender.

Comment: That question will probably be closed as any answers will be opinion-based which are off-topic here. Suggest you ask on the BlenderArtists web site or look through some of the hundreds of YT tutorials to find something suitable for your level.

Comment: I see , thank you

Comment: That would depend a great deal on what class of character you wanted to model.  Are you looking to model stylized characters or do you want to achieve a great degree of realism?  Are you interested in single characters for still images or do you want them to be easy to animate?  If you want to animate are you thinking about doing your own rigging?